# Criterion for relative Deligne-Mumfordness?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-stacks

A quotient stack $X/G$ of a scheme by a *smooth* algebraic group is Deligne-Mumford if and only if (approximately) the stabiliser groups of points are finite (for the precise statement see corollary 8.4.2 of Olsson's book *algebraic spaces and stacks*).

**Question:** Say $X\to Y$ is a map of general Artin stacks, and $G$ is a group scheme over $Y$. Then is there a similar criterion that $X/G\to Y$ is "relative Deligne Mumford"?

I'm not sure what the correct notion of a relative Deligne Mumford stack is, but I imagine it's something like: "$W\to Z$ is relative Deligne Mumford if for any DM stack $Z'$ with a map $Z'\to Z$, the pullback $W\times_ZZ'$ is DM" or some slight variation on that.

Comment: (1) Your criterion seems to be equivalent to " $W \to Z$ is relative Deligne-Mumford if for any scheme $U$ with a map $U \to Z$, the pullback $W \times_Z U$ is Deligne-Mumford" by considering the etale map $U \to Z'$ that exists by Deligne-Mumford-ness of $Z'$.  (2) I think you will have problems if $G$ is not a smooth group scheme. Take $Y = \mathbb A^1$ with coordinate $t$, $X = \mathbb A^1 \times \mathbb G_m$ with coordinate $\lambda$, $G$ the subgroup of $X$ defined by the equation $ (\lambda-1)t =0$, and look at the quotient $X / G$. This is not Deligne-Mumford.

Comment: @WillSawin For (2) you are completely right, I've added to the prelude that in Olsson $G$ is also required for that corollary to work.

Comment: It seems to me like it should be true if $X \to Y$ is schematic, $G$ is smooth over $Y$, and $X/G$ has finite "relative stabilizers" by base-changing everything to a scheme over $Y$. Is this the kind of criterion you are looking for?

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, that's precisely it. I realise this is probably trivial, but I've had a hard time defining relative stabilisers.

Comment: @Meow Check out https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/050P The notion of "relative inertia stack" seems relevant.